# Finding extension of an URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

i have a string named url  i.e

```
NSString *url = @"http://sound17.mp3pk.com/indian/barfi/%5BSongs.PK%5D%20
                  Barfi%20-%2001%20-%20Barfi!.mp3";
```

Now I want that It should search from last upto the .(dot)

i.e it should search 
 `mp3` in string as it is coming after .(dot) and want to store that `mp3` in the temporary variable.
how can i use `lastindex(".")` or something else to store in temporary variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
NSString *extension = [url pathExtension];
```

Comment: ya thanx for ur reply.can u why we are using pathExtension.and i think If I use this IT will search for specific extension but i want it for any extension. like mp3,mp4...

Comment: @SameSungVsIphone Because it does exactly what you want. It searches an NSString for a file extension. Read the docs.

Comment: @DrummerB thanx man! it works for me!  one more thing I want to ask that now Is it possible to store the name of file also... which is  " %5BSongs.PK%5D%20Barfi%20-%2001%20-%20Barfi! "  in my string nd these url formatter..

Comment: Use `lastPathComponent`, `pathExtension` and `substringToIndex:`.